# How do you hide tool tips in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to hide the tool tips that popup when you hover over objects? Especially when you hover over tables, I do not want to see the breakdown of what objects are in that table.

Comment: Can't find the answer anywhere either, this is driving me crazy when you move a table, the tooltip appears and your table jumps away from the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Philip Olson on the mysql.com bug system](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72257), this is "fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.1.6 release".

Comment: Ive tested the new release workbench 6.1.6 and they have addressed the issue, works great now

Comment: This seems not solved yet, see the image in my reply.

Comment: @DUKE The question is how to hide the tooltips, not how to prevent them from appearing.

Comment: @DUKE well for anyone looking to hide them, just click on the table and it will go away lol